# Will_paginate Plugin on two objects on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, will-paginate

Hello I am using will_paginte plugin on two objects on a same page. Like on stackoverflow. There is a profile page on which there is a pagination on two things 
QUestions and answers.

I am having  problem ie:--
when user is clicking on questions pagination page 2. answers page are also updating. The reason is both is sending a post variable ie

```
  params[:page]
```

How to change this variable so that only one should be updated. and how to maintain that user should not lose the other page.

ie

he is on 3rd page of questions and 1st page of answers and now he click on 5th page of the questions the result should be 3rd page of questions and 5th page of answers.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can specify a `:param_name` option to tell will_paginate the name of the parameter to use for the page number within URLs (the default is `:page`). So you could do:

```
<%= will_paginate @questions, :param_name => 'questions_page' %>
<%= will_paginate @answers, :param_name => 'answers_page' %>
```

- [will_paginate documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation)

Comment: Make sure to update your controller such like: `@questions = Question.paginate(:page => params[:question_page], :per_page => 10)` AND `
@answers = Answer.paginate(:page => params[:answer_page], :per_page => 10)`