# Rails: handling two paged lists on single view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, named-scope

Assuming following model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account

  scope :active, -> { where('orders.state = ?', 'ACTIVE') }
  scope :closed, -> { where('orders.state <> ?', 'ACTIVE') }

end
```

In `account/show` view I have two lists: one for active orders and other with closed ones.

Now I need to add a paging for each of the lists (using `will_paginate` gem) but I don't know what is the best way to route the requests for that and how to handle two collections in the controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069064/will-paginate-plugin-on-two-objects-on-same-page), you need to set to set different `:param_name` values for your two calls to will_paginate:

```
<%= will_paginate @orders.active, :param_name => 'active_page' %>
<%= will_paginate @orders.closed, :param_name => 'closed_page' %>
```

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation

Comment: How about controller? to what collection should I apply `.page()` filter?

Comment: figured it out. instead of `@orders.active` created instance var `@active_orders = @account.orders.active.page(params['active_page'])`.